# how to call a sql variable in javascript selected by html onchange, canned response function

Tags: php, javascript, sql

What I want to be able to do is to:

--- have an "on change" on drop list (containing the table data "titles")

--- this on change runs the javascript function

--- the javascript populates a text area with a "message" column of data in the same table   as the corresponding title that is being selected in the drop list.

```
<li><label for="frm_precan">Canned Response</label>
            <span class="input">                        
                    <select id="frm_precan" name="precan" onchange="updateText();">
                            <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
                            <?php foreach($precan_list as $precan) : ?>
                            <option value="<?=$precan['id'];?>"><?=$precan['name'];?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>            
                    </select>
            </span>
        </li>
        </ul>   
        <textarea style="width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-width: 1; font-family: courier;" name="message" rows="10" id="text_area"></textarea>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateText()
            {
            var value = $("#frm_precan option:selected").text();
            $('#text_area').val(value);;
            }
        </script>
```

This is the code, and it currently can put the selected title in the text area. However, I need to get data from database according to selected index of the dropdown and fill the textbox with it. How can I do this?

Comment: your question isn't clear, can you further explain what you want is?

Comment: sorry im having trouble explaining what i need to do. the function i am building is essentially a precanned response function. so you would select a drop down list that currently contains a for each loop populated with an sql tables name field. as it is, the code can populate the textarea with this field, however i wish to use the selected name field as a WHERE condition i guess and display a different table column such as message, WHERE name or title = the title selected in the drop down box?? sorry if this doesnt make sense.

Comment: so you want to fill a textbox according to selected index of the dropdown menu. also, this filling is done with the matching database row. am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fill the textbox with pure JavaScript. JavaScript works client-side and you need to access the database on a change of selection in the dropdown menu. For that, you need to recall the same page on a dropdown selection change. After you get the data from database, it's easy to create a textbox with the data with "echo" command.

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['my_selection'])) {
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['my_selection'])."'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "<input type='text' value='".$row['column']."'>";
    echo "<input type='text' value='".$row['column1']."'>";
}
?>
<select name='my_selection'>
Your existing select box here...
```

Comment: OK thanks. I am sorry but i am still not following how to call this from an on change  property on the drop list, and i am aware that this wants to go to a javascript function that presumably calls the php method obtaining the SQL stuff.

Comment: place the "select" into a form and enter the file's name into it's "action" tag.